# Plotting two y's on the same x with different colors?

Tags: r

```
temp1<- data.frame(x =(1:10), y=(1:10)^2)

temp2<- data.frame(x =(1:10), y=(1:10)^3)

# plot(temp1$x, with both temp1$y and temp2$y; 
# want each represented by a different color)
```

is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
plot(temp2, type="l", col="green")
lines(temp1, col="red")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
matplot(temp1$x, cbind(temp1$y, temp2$y), t="l", lty=1, col=c("red", "blue"))
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y, colour=which, geom="path", data=lattice::make.groups(temp1, temp2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could achieve this using ggplot2. Assuming your dataset looks like this:

```
x      y   category
1      3   A
3.2   4   B
```

You can plot two lines with different colors using:

```
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=category), data = dat) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it is. See `?plot`, and the `col` (colour) argument for the colour.

As to getting them both on the *same* plot you can either use `lines`/`points` (which draw on the existing plot) or see `?par` and the `new` option.

In particular, `par(new=TRUE)` *doesn't* clean the current plot device, allowing you to draw on top (a bit counter-intuitive, I know).

So:

```
# plot temp1 y vs x in blue
plot(y~x, temp1, col='blue')

# draw the next plot on the same plot
par(new=TRUE)

# plot temp2 y vs x in red, on the SAME plot (new=TRUE)
plot(y~x, temp2, col='red')
```

If you wanted to use `lines`/`points`, instead of doing the `par(new=TRUE)` and second `plot`, just do `lines(y~x,temp2,...)`